# I get a error saying that the all variable cannot be bound

Tags: oracle, plsql

I try to implement this code i get a error that all variable or not bond. whats the best solution for me. 
I am trying to implement this code for declaring the variable out side the block and call them into the program.

```
variable b_salary employees.salary%type;

declare 
   v_name employees.last_name%type;
   v_salary employees.salary%type;
BEGIN    

   select last_name,salary
   into   v_name, :b_salary
   from   employees
   where  phone_number = '9856849658';

   dbms_output.put_line ('EMP ' || V_name || ' earns ' || V_salary || ' monthly ');
   dbms_output.put_line ('Hello Word') ;
END;
```

Comment: delete the colon ':b_salary'

Comment: Why have you defined both b_salary and v_salary? Sounds like you just need v_salary...

Comment: Please **[EDIT]** your question and add the **exact** error message you get. **[edit]** your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This declaration is not allowed in SQL-Plus:

```
variable b_salary employees.salary%type;
```

Moreover, if you run this line in SQL-Plus or SQL-Develoer, you will get the below error message with usage instructions, I wonder why you didn't notice it:

```
Usage: VAR[IABLE] [ <variable> [ NUMBER | CHAR | CHAR (n [CHAR|BYTE]) |
    VARCHAR2 (n [CHAR|BYTE]) | NCHAR | NCHAR (n) |
    NVARCHAR2 (n) | CLOB | NCLOB | BLOB | BFILE
    REFCURSOR | BINARY_FLOAT | BINARY_DOUBLE ] ]
```

You can use only exact type name, one from the above message, `employees.salary%type` is not allowed here.